# What does this ODE mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition, distribution-theory

I'm interested in understanding the following system of linear ODE's. Consider $\mu \leq 0$ and the system
\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}u(t) = \mu u, \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad u(0)=1,\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} v(s,t) = \delta(t-s)u + \mu v \quad v(s,0)=0 \: \forall s 
\end{cases}
I know the solutions to be $u(t) = e^{\mu t}$ and $$v(s,t) = \begin{cases}
e^{\mu t} \quad \text{if } t\geq s \geq 0 \\
0 \quad \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I'm a bit confused as to what it means to be a solution to the second ode in our system above. The Dirac delta distribution is throwing me off. What I expect the solution of the second system be is the following; $v$ is a solution to the second ODE if for all $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ that
$$\int_\mathbb{R} v (s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(s,t) = u(s)\phi(s) +  \mu \int_\mathbb{R} \phi (s,t)v(s,t).$$

This is merely an educated guess from my limited knowledge of distribution theory. When I go to verify this I get a minus sign on the left hand side, but also I'm not even sure if this is even correct.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made an error and missed a minus sign. The distributional derivative of $f$ is defined by
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx = - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \phi'(x) \, dx
$$
so it should be
$$
-\int_\mathbb{R} v (s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(s,t) = u(s)\phi(s) +  \mu \int_\mathbb{R} \phi (s,t)v(s,t).
$$

Practically, if $f$ is piecewise smooth, $f'(x) = \delta(x-a)$ means that $f$ has a step discontinuity at $x=a$ with $f(a+) - f(a-) = 1,$ where $f(a\pm) = \lim_{x\to a\pm} f(x).$

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! I was trying to piece this together from the fundamental solution of Laplace's equation i can now see where i went wrong. Do you know any good books that deal with distributions in PDE theory? Preferably springer as i have access to their books.

Comment: The theory of distributions can often be found in books about the Fourier transform, like [Fourier Analysis and Its Applications by Anders Vretblad](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387008363). When I studied distributions back in the 90's, we used photocopies of [The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I - Distribution Theory and Fourier Analysis by Lars Hörmander](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540006626).

Comment: For some reason, I suggested only Swedish authors. So let me give you a third Swedish suggestion, not a book this time, just a PDF: [Lecture Notes on Distributions by Hasse Carlsson](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~hasse/distributioner_eng.pdf)